# Using numpy functions which numba doesn't support

Tags: python, performance, numpy, numba

I am currently using a function to create histograms using `numpy.histogram()` and `numpy.histogram2d()`. To speed up the process using `numba`, I tried to use `@jit` decorator to interpret in `nonpython` mode, but `numba` reported an error saying `numpy.histogram()` is an unsupported function.  My function looks something like,

```py
def make_histograms(X, neurons, bins = 5):
    xy = np.histogram2d(X, neurons, bins)[0]
    x = np.histogram(X, bins)[0]
    y = np.histogram(neurons, bins)[0]
```

Is there any other work around to use numba for my case? Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: If you really want to do this, look at the [source](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.16.1/numpy/lib/histograms.py#L666-L916) to `histogram`.  You could almost certainly work with that to make it compatible with `numba`, although it would be much more verbose than what you're trying now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Numba` documentation itself provides an example to utilize `Numba` for histograms. That looks quite handy; however, implementing 2d histogram looks quite abstruse and involving. Fortunately, I found this awesome [repo](https://github.com/astrofrog/fast-histogram) which implements `fast_histogram` computation with performance improvement equal or sometimes more than Numba. Also, this [page](https://iscinumpy.gitlab.io/post/histogram-speeds-in-python/) compare their performance. 
I am leaving this answer here myself, hoping that it would be useful for someone.